# Get the count of continous occurences of string in a column of dataframe based on another column

Tags: r, aggregate

I need to find out how many times one value occurs after another in a column of a certain data frame.

The main logic is to get the no of occurrences of a specific string based on another column.

For example:

```
df<- data.frame(fruits = c("apples", "apples", "orange", "pears", "apples", "pears", "pears", "papaya", "papaya"), 
                veggies = c("beans", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots", "brinjal","carrots", "brinjal", "brinjal", "beans"),
                branches=c( "Area1", "Area1", "Area1", "Area2","Area2","Area2", "Area2", "Area3", "Area3" ))
```

This s my data frame. i need to know the count of fruits or veggies based on branches column

When I use  `table(df$fruits)`

the output is:

```
apples-3 orange-1 papaya-2  pears-3
```

The output commonly showing total count of apples and rest of the fruits for all branches. I need to get the count exactly for each branches.

My required output should based on column `df$Branches`

```
for Area1
   apples-2 orange-1,
for Area2 
   pears-3 apples-1
for Area3 
   papaya-3
```

Comment: This is called ***aggregating***. Specifically you want to aggregate fruits or veggies, by branches.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,list(count=.N),list(branches, fruits)]

#   branches fruits count
#1:    Area1 apples     2
#2:    Area1 orange     1
#3:    Area2  pears     3
#4:    Area2 apples     1
#5:    Area3 papaya     2
```

Comment: thanks for your response colonel....but it throwing error for me
Error in setDT(df) :
  Can not convert 'df' to data.table by reference because binding is locked. It is very likely that 'df' resides within a package (or an environment) that is locked to prevent modifying its variable bindings. Try copying the object to your current environment, ex: var <- copy(var) and then using setDT again.

Comment: can you do df1=df and then apply the above on df1?

Comment: @Neha, the error message you've pasted tells exactly what to do!

Comment: One more reason to use data.table error messages are really verbose!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just use `ftable`:

```
> ftable(fruits ~ branches, data = df)
         fruits apples orange papaya pears
branches                                  
Area1                2      1      0     0
Area2                1      0      0     3
Area3                0      0      2     0
> ftable(veggies ~ branches, data = df)
         veggies beans brinjal carrots
branches                              
Area1                1       0       2
Area2                0       2       2
Area3                1       1       0
```

Comment: can we get the count based on timestamp column for specific intervals? eg., between 10 min interval can we get the count of repeated string ? Is that possible?

Comment: @Neha Your example data do not have have a timestamp. If you have a more specific question, please edit your original post to include this information and your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the ouput you are expecting but you can get the counts using the dplyr package :

For example :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% count(fruits, branches)
# OR
count(df, fruits, branches)
```

Output :

```
Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
Groups: fruits

  fruits branches n
1 apples    Area1 2
2 apples    Area2 1
3 orange    Area1 1
4 papaya    Area3 2
5  pears    Area2 3
```

Comment: For example, Am having date with time column in a data.frame from 05-SEP-14 07.22.13 AM to 05-SEP-14 10.22.13 PM..can i get the count of apples sold for every 30 minutes?